# Is that possible to use "Invoke-SqlCmd" as a part of Visual Studio Online build step?

Tags: sql, powershell, azure, tfsbuild, azure-devops

We try to get our DB updated as part of the Visual Studio Online build as dedicated build step, but the PowerShell script that we locally using fails to work on the hosted build controller with following error.

```
2015-07-28T20:35:26.8546681Z ##[error]import-module : The specified module 'sqlps' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module 

2015-07-28T20:35:26.8546681Z ##[error]directory.
```

Is there any way to use "Invoke-SqlCmd" in VSO hosted build controller?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with those lines!

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 1):

Here how I do it:

```
$moduleName = "SqlServer"

if (Get-Module $moduleName -ListAvailable) {
    Write-Host "Module '$moduleName' is available"
} else {
    Write-Host "Module '$moduleName' does not exist"
    try {
        Install-Module -Name $moduleName -Force -AllowClobber
        Write-Host "Module '$moduleName' successfully installed"
    } catch {
        Throw "Installation of module '$moduleName' failed: $($_.Exception)"
    }
}
```